# How to import all express routes defined in different files using `import`

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Folder structure

```
index.js
modules/users/users.server.routes.js
```

modules/users/users.server.routes.js

```
export default (app) => {
     app.route('/api', (req, res) => {
        res.send('User routes working');
     });
};
```

index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

/*
* For iterating through files using a regex
* */
import glob from 'glob';

let files = glob.sync('app/**/*.routes.js');
files = files.map((file) => {
    import(file);
});

const app = express();
const config = {
    app_port: 8080
};

/*
* Test route
* */
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Voila!!');
});
```

Above code is giving an error!

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

What I want to achieve is, once the server gets started, all the routes should be imported. (Live require(--route file--))

I don't want to declare all the routes in a single routes file like this.

```
// mount user routes at /users
router.use('/users', userRoutes);

// mount auth routes at /auth
router.use('/auth', authRoutes);
```

I want each route to be defined from the root of the API.

How to achieve this in ES6 way?

Thank you all!

Comment: And even if dynamic imports were supported they return a promise. So you'd need to await for all imports.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this. I will check adding await.

Comment: But this only makes sense if dynamice imports were supported by the runtime you are using. As the error message says they don't

Comment: Yeah. But what is the best way to import routes dynamically? Or its is not a practice to be followed with ES6?